# How to prevent TimePickerDialog supposed to be opened after clicking a spinner item from opening automatically?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-calendar, timepickerdialog

I have a `spinner` which has only one item named `Pick a time..`. A `TimePickerDialog` should open after clicking a this item.

Here's my code:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener endTimeListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1,
                                       int i, long arg3) {

                final TextView endTimeSpinnerTV = (TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0);

                switch (i) {
                    default:
                        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        mHourEnd = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        mMinuteEnd = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(PostSportRequest.this,
                                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                          int minute) {

                                        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                                        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                                        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                                        date.set(Calendar.AM_PM, date.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

                                        showTimeEnd(hourOfDay, minute);

                                        userAvailableTillTimeInSF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());

                                        endTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(date.getTime());

                                        endTimeSpinnerTV.setText(userAvailableTillTimeAMPM);

                                    }
                                }, mHourEnd, mMinuteEnd, false);
                        timePickerDialog.show();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

SpinnerOnSameSelection endTimeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(endTimeListener);
```

Here's `SpinnerOnSameSelection` class:

```
public class SpinnerOnSameSelection extends Spinner {
    OnItemSelectedListener listener;
    private AdapterView<?> lastParent;
    private View lastView;
    private long lastId;

    public SpinnerOnSameSelection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initlistner();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        if (position == getSelectedItemPosition() && listener != null) {
            listener.onItemSelected(lastParent, lastView, position, lastId);
        } else {
            super.setSelection(position);
        }

    }

    private void initlistner() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                lastParent = parent;
                lastView = view;
                lastId = id;
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onNothingSelected(parent);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(
            OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

and here's `showTimeEnd(int hour, int min)`:

```
public void showTimeEnd(int hour, int min) {
        if (hour == 0) {
            hour += 12;
            format = "AM";
        } else if (hour == 12) {
            format = "PM";
        } else if (hour > 12) {
            hour -= 12;
            format = "PM";
        } else {
            format = "AM";
        }

        userAvailableTillTimeAMPM = hour + ":" + min + " " + format;

}
```

**The problem is that** as I open the activity, the `TimePickerDialog` opens up automatically.

**How can I** prevent this from happening?

Comment: I'll guess that you are setting a value on the spinner. If so, the item selection change and it will fire your listener. I had that issue too and I solved using a `TextView`instead of a spinner. Show the pickerDialog when the user clicks on the TextView

Comment: let me know if it solves your problem. Then I'll turn it into an answer

Comment: @EduardoHerzer I have to use `Spinner`. I can't use `TextView` here.

Comment: I don't see a reason, but ok. Try to set the listener **after** the  spinner value... That should do the trick

Comment: I think the problem is inside of your activity. Can you post the code for that class?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer please tell more clearly using code.

Comment: So when the Activity loads the Spinner is setting the default value to show and that in turn is triggering your onItemSelectedListener which is then causing TimePickerDialog to show. Does that sum up your problem?

Comment: @DanielOchoa exactly... yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are setting the listener before the value. So the listener gets fired:

```
 endTimeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(endTimeListener);
 endTimeSpinner.setSelection(1);
```

You must invert it. First set the selection and then set the listener

```
 endTimeSpinner.setSelection(1);
 endTimeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(endTimeListener);
```

Edit:

I'm pretty sure it would work better if you use a `TextView` with a clickListener.

But if you really need the Spinner, try not calling your listener if the position is 0:

```
private void initlistner() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lastParent = parent;
            lastView = view;
            lastId = id;
            if (listener != null && position > 0) {
                listener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onNothingSelected(parent);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: what is `endTimeSpinner.setSelection(1);`. I have no such line of code.

Comment: @HammadNasir how are you setting the value of the spinner?

Comment: do you mean how am I assigning the value to spinner? It has been declared in strings file like this: `<string-array name="pEndTimeList">
        <item>Pick a time..</item>
    </string-array>` and then set in xml file as `android:entries="@array/pEndTimeList"`

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve it is to set your listener like this:

```
 endTimeSpinner.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            endTimeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(endTimeListener);
        }
    })
```